# How do I Get a count of a value that may be found in one of two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

If I had a table with values

```
Game Id | Home     | Away   |
------- | -------- |------- |
0       | Team A   | Team B |
1       | Team C   | Team D |
2       | Team B   | Team C |
3       | Team D   | Team C |
```

In SQL, how would I get a Count of each team regardless of whether they were Home or Away.

E.g.

```
    Team    | Count   
    ------- | ----- 
    Team A  | 1 
    Team B  | 2   
    Team C  | 3   
    Team D  | 2
```

My hack in python was to split into two tables of counts, and merge the tables together but I think there is a much better way to do this in SQL

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: thanks, i'm using postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `unpivot` the data and do the `count`

You can use `Unnest` and `Array` to unpivot the data. `Unnest` converts an `array` to a set of rows

```
SELECT   unnest(array["Home", "Away"]) AS team, 
         count(1) 
FROM     yourtable 
GROUP BY team
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/PHBUNR24245)

Comment: adapted this to my needs, works perfectly http://rextester.com/WPFT66751

Comment: Can't you just do `group by team`?  (Clever answer.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - In `postgres` can we use alias name in `group by` ?

Comment: @Prdp . . . Yes, you can.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL, you would use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select team, count(*)
from ((select home as team from t) union all
      (select away from t)
     ) t
group by team;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this.
Count on Home column, count on away, union both and count again.

```
SELECT Team,
       sum(occurrence) AS count
FROM
    ( SELECT Home AS Team,
             count(*) AS occurrence
     GROUP BY Home
     UNION ALL SELECT Away AS Team,
                  count(*) AS occurrence
     GROUP BY Away) AS lookup
```

Comment: Should be `Union ALL`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I changed it. Even though the answer from Gordon is way more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[Grouping Sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS):

```
with t (game_id, home, away) as ( values
    (0,'Team A','Team B'),
    (1,'Team C','Team D'),
    (2,'Team B','Team C'),
    (3,'Team D','Team C')
)
select coalesce(home, away) as team, sum(total) as total
from (
    select home, away, count(*) as total
    from t
    group by grouping sets (home, away)
) s
group by 1
order by 1
;
  team  | total 
--------+-------
 Team A |     1
 Team B |     2
 Team C |     3
 Team D |     2
```